# How exactly to specify Qt5 path to CMake?

Tags: linux, cmake, debian, qt5

I'm currently trying to build the latest version of MuseScore 4, whose source I pulled from the official GitHub repo by simply cloning the latter locally.

I keep on getting the following error when running `./build.cmake`:

```
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
CMake Error at build.cmake:232 (message):
  Configure step failed with status 1.  See output above for details.
```

I've created a file `build_overrides.cmake` where I've placed the single following line:

```
set(ENV{QTDIR} "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu") # Qt5 library location
```

After all, running `qmake --version` returns the following:

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.15.2 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

And running `whereis qmake` returns `qt5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 /usr/lib/qt5 /usr/share/qt5`.

I've also tried the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5`, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin`, `/usr/lib/qt5` and `/usr/share/qt5` directories, but the previously mentioned error keeps on popping up again. I'm assuming I'm not including my Qt5 installation path properly in `build_overrides.cmake`. What should I change for the compilation to run successfully?

I'm running GNU/Linux Debian Bullseye (11) AMD64, and a backported version of CMake (3.25.1-1~bpo11+1, in other words, a patched 3.25.1 version). My Qt version is 3.1, as you've certainly noticed in the output above.

### Edit:

Grepping for `'clang'` (`ls -aR | grep clang`) in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` returns the following:

```
libclang-11.so.1
libclang-cpp.so.11
android-clang
freebsd-clang
linux-clang
linux-clang-32
linux-clang-libc++
linux-clang-libc++-32
macx-clang
macx-ios-clang
macx-tvos-clang
macx-watchos-clang
win32-clang-g++
win32-clang-msvc
./qt5/mkspecs/android-clang:
clang.conf
clang-mac.conf
clang.conf
freebsd-generic-clang
freebsd-rasp-pi-clang
./qt5/mkspecs/devices/freebsd-generic-clang:
./qt5/mkspecs/devices/freebsd-rasp-pi-clang:
./qt5/mkspecs/freebsd-clang:
./qt5/mkspecs/linux-clang:
./qt5/mkspecs/linux-clang-32:
./qt5/mkspecs/linux-clang-libc++:
./qt5/mkspecs/linux-clang-libc++-32:
./qt5/mkspecs/macx-clang:
./qt5/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang:
./qt5/mkspecs/macx-ios-clang/features:
./qt5/mkspecs/macx-tvos-clang:
./qt5/mkspecs/macx-watchos-clang:
./qt5/mkspecs/win32-clang-g++:
./qt5/mkspecs/win32-clang-msvc:
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. I was wondering the same thing, but obediently followed the instructions in this wiki: https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore/wiki/Compile-on-the-command-line#linux I'll try removing it and see what that gives.

Comment: relevant source: https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore/blob/v4.0.2/build.cmake#L88 says "Typical value for ENV{QTDIR}: /path/to/Qt/<version>/<compiler>" you don't seem to be including a compiler part in the path you're using?

Comment: also, the wiki you're referencing does `$ENV{HOME}`, which refereneces the `HOME` environment variable. What you wrote is illegitimate CMake syntax :P

Comment: @starball Oh, thanks for pointing that out! I omitted `$ENV` completely, and tried all the directories I mentioned in my question again, but still the error occurs.

Comment: @starball Oh sorry, I didn't see that. How do I find my compiler? I assume it's the GCC by default? I did `ls -aR | grep gcc` but didn't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: try also grepping for "clang" and "msvc". Wht platform (OS) are you on?

Comment: @starball Debian Bullseye. I edited the question to include the output when grepping for 'clang'. Not sure what to do from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254323/discussion-between-gpwr-and-starball).

Comment: There should be `Qt5Config.cmake` somewher in your installation. If you installed the package `qt5-dev` package (or whatever it's called) via apt, I don't expect it to be necessary to pass any info about the qt location at all. If there is, setting the `Qt5_ROOT` cache variable should do the trick.(On my windows machine you'd need to set this to `"D:/Qt/6.4.1/msvc2019_64` for the config file being installed at `D:\Qt\6.4.1\msvc2019_64\lib\cmake\Qt6`; just choose the equivalent for your qt/os version). Note: I assume`find_package(Qt5)`is used to find qt; don't know, if this is the case for muse